# display image with fixed width and height without warping/distorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a page on my site which gets a load of images from the database and puts them in a grid.

The images are all different shapes and sizes.

What I want to do is display the images, each with the **same width and height** but without them becoming distorted.

right now my css is

```
.image{
 width:100px;
 height:100px
}
```

But obviously this leads to images being warped out of their normal dimensions.

I can't just set the height or width because I want the whole 100x100 px block to be filled with image.

I guess I need to create something which makes new image thumbnails out of the original images. Would I have to actually edit the image files when they are copied to the server? Or is there some javascript I could do which could display the images like this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you create a `<div>` of that size and set the `background-image: url(/my/image.jpg);`?  That would work if you didn't have thumbnails, but having thumbnail versions would be much better (and faster to load)

Comment: Create a container div around each image with 100px width and 100px height and add overflow: hidden to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.image{
min-height:100px;
height:100px;
min-width:100px;
width:100px;
}
```

or create div around the images with a height of 100px and a width of 100px.